# How would I make a word print backwards in python?

Tags: python

How would I make a word print backwards in Python? For example, if I have this:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
```

how would I make that print backwards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest one, using [`extended slice`](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) :

```
>>> word[::-1]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : word = 'abcd'
OUT : 'dcba'
```

Comment: Hey Kaushik, can you elaborate more on the logic? This solution seems to be lovely.

Comment: @thatrockbottomprogrammer : Check my edit. Have posted the link for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
a=input()
print ("".join(reversed(a)))
```